# Vim runs shell command turning Chinese character into sign '?'

Tags: vim, encoding

I've tried to run `set .*encoding` (for example, `encoding`, `fileencoding`, etc.) into `utf-8` but the question does not solved.

The question is: when I run command in normal shell, everything going well:

```
$ make SQL
+-----+-----------+------------------+-------+
| Sno | Sname     | Cname            | Grade |
+-----+-----------+------------------+-------+
| 01  | Peter     | C Language       |  98.1 |
| 01  | Peter     | Data Struct      |  89.3 |
...
| 08  | 王小明    | NULL             |  NULL |
| 09  | 王明儿    | NULL             |  NULL |
| 10  | A明B      | NULL             |  NULL |
| 11  | A明B      | NULL             |  NULL |
...
+-----+-----------+------------------+-------+
```

It works well, but when I run it under vim with vim-command `:r!make SQL`, it will print with '?' sign:

```
+-----+-----------+------------------+-------+
| Sno | Sname     | Cname            | Grade |
+-----+-----------+------------------+-------+
| 01  | Peter     | C Language       |  98.1 |
| 01  | Peter     | Data Struct      |  89.3 |
...
| 08  | ???       | NULL             |  NULL |
| 09  | ???       | NULL             |  NULL |
| 10  | A?B       | NULL             |  NULL |
| 11  | A?B       | NULL             |  NULL |
...
+-----+-----------+------------------+-------+
```

I am not sure what happen, but I have a solution that can work:

1. Run `make SQL > tmp` in shell.
2. Run `:r!cat tmp` in vim.

I also know that `:r!make SQL > tmp && cat tmp` still has the '?' problem. I do want to use `r!make SQL` directly in vim, and that's why I ask this question. Thanks for your help.

The `:r!locale`'s result is:

```
locale: Cannot set LC_CTYPE to default locale: No such file or directory
locale: Cannot set LC_MESSAGES to default locale: No such file or directory
locale: Cannot set LC_ALL to default locale: No such file or directory
LANG=en
LANGUAGE=
LC_CTYPE="en"
LC_NUMERIC="en"
LC_TIME="en"
LC_COLLATE="en"
LC_MONETARY="en"
LC_MESSAGES="en"
LC_PAPER="en"
LC_NAME="en"
LC_ADDRESS="en"
LC_TELEPHONE="en"
LC_MEASUREMENT="en"
LC_IDENTIFICATION="en"
LC_ALL=
```

Comment: What do you get when you do `:r!locale`?

Comment: `:help 'encoding'`, `:help 'fileencoding'`, and `:help 'fileencodings'` only affect Vim itself. If you want to work in utf-8, you will have to make sure your whole system is configured for that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`en` is not a valid locale on many systems, and even where accepted, it's not going to have the results you want.  Typically a locale is of the format `xx_XX.CHARSET`, where `xx` is a language code, `XX` is a country code, and `CHARSET` is a character set.  For example, you could write `en_US.UTF-8` for American English with UTF-8, or `fr_CH.UTF-8` for Swiss French with UTF-8.

Because most Unix operating systems precede the existence of UTF-8 (macOS being a possible exception), generally the default locales on a system are not UTF-8, so if you specify a locale that does not declare UTF-8 explicitly, your tools will not use UTF-8.

As a result, you'll need to set your locale appropriately, in the format above, so that your system uses UTF-8 everywhere.  That will make programs behave correctly.

Specifically to Vim, if you read data in from a piped command like this, Vim will do character set detection (controlled by `fileencodings`).  If you don't have `encoding` set and your locale is a Unicode locale, Vim will look for a byte-order mark, then Unicode, and then default to `latin1`.  If it's not a Unicode locale and the value is not set, then Vim will just your current locale, which is probably going to be interpreted as `latin1`, and you'll be sad.  This looks like what's happening here.

You can, of course, adjust `encoding`, `fileencoding`, and `fileencodings`, but the easiest way to get sane behavior in Vim and across all programs is to set your locale to one that uses UTF-8.